# Где бы (ни) работать, как не здесь?

Tags: орфография

Какой (или какие) из вариантов грамматически корректен:

Где бы работать, как не здесь?
Где бы ни работать, как не здесь?
Где бы не работать, как не здесь?

Почему-то фраза производит странное впечатление во всех вариантах.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы частицу поменяла: Где же работать, как не здесь?

Comment: Я бы тоже. Но я эту фразу услышал именно с "бы". Было там "ни" или "не" не знаю.

Comment: С НЕ не подходит. Получается, что человек хочет здесь НЕ работать.
НИ тоже не подходит. Из трех "зол" выбрала бы наименьшее - без частицы НЕ(НИ).

Comment: C невозможностью "не" согласен, с аргументацией - не совсем.  
Сравните: **Где бы ни работать, лишь бы не здесь**. Именно что не хочет. А все равно "ни".

Почему НИ не подходит? В этом-то и вопрос. 
  
По поводу "трёх зол" - ситуация не подходит. Представьте, что я не выбираю, а оцениваю уже выбранное на предмет ошибки и снижения, скажем, оценки за грамматику. Тут вопрос не лучше-хуже, а нельзя-можно.

Comment: Тогда нельзя. И см. ответ1.

Answer (score 0):

Где ж ещё работать, как не здесь?

Comment: В предложенном мной варианте отрицательная частица "не" однозначно исключает все другие варианты работы, выраженные в данном случае словечком "ещё".

Comment: Спасибо, только, во-первых, было, а во-вторых меня  интересовал услышанный вариант, а не как его править. С ещё - это понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Или первый вариант, или третий. В зависимости от смысла.

Comment: Спасибо. Смысл - по вашему выбору. Речь о грамматике.

Comment: Кстати, можно и без частицы "бы": "Где работать, как не здесь?" Звучит по-моему еще более благообразно.